# Where to find a selection of images I could explore for creativeness?

Tags: software-rec, images, website

Is there any website / method to generate a random list of 10 or whatever number of images and just show on screen those images?
I would like to have this just when I am stuck writing a text, I look at the 5 or 10 random images and then try to find relationships between the images and parts of my problem. Sometimes new ideas arise. Any opinions / help?

Comment: Voting to move to webapps.stackexchange.com if you are looking for an already established solution, though if you are looking to actually code this, maybe stackoverflow would be better.

Comment: What about http://www.flickr.com/explore/interesting/7days/ ?

Comment: yes, this seems to be a good idea although the images seem to be a bit biased (landscapes, people, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try [Google Image search](http://www.google.ca/imghp) and type a random word (usually an adjective) that would generate random image sets (like "Large" or "Alternative"). Safe search highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that wouldn't be very hard to code in any number of languages.  You just need a program which gathers a list of available images, assigns each a number from 1 to X, then generates y number of random numbers between 1 and X and displays the images that have been assigned to those numbers by the application.  Fairly easy coding for .NET, Java, PHP, etc.